# Default.Master for CSS reference

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I am trying to find the master page my non-publishing site uses.
The `Home.aspx` page shows a reference to `Default.Master` however I dont have a `Default.master`. I do however have to master pages that have the option to make it the default (`V4.master` and `minimal.master`) but its far from intutive as to which master page I need to add my CSS reference too

Answer (score 0):

Following instructions require you are a "site collection administrator" (SCA)

In Site Settings `/_layouts/Settings.aspx` there should be a Master page gallery `/_catalogs/masterpage` which is a library that will contain each master page document.

You mention it is a non-publishing site but you could still enable "SharePoint Server Publishing Infastructure" from the Site Collection Features `/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx?scope=site` (not site featues) in site settings. This would provide 'Master Pages' `/_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage` under 'look and feel' which allows you to see/change the current master page.

Please Note:

Best practice would be to make a copy of the master page which you edit and than set your site to use the new copy you edited/renamed

Comment: However, I dont have a MasterPage option because I dont have publishing on. I am hoping to make these CSS changes without turning on publishing

Comment: Does this basically mean its not possible to make any style sheet changes without Publishing on?

Comment: I don't have a platform available for additional testing but why is it that you cannot enable publishing at the site collection level. The only noticeable changes are the one you want